# How does instagram upload high quality images and videos with no lag?

Tags: objective-c, image, video, compression, avfoundation

I am building an app similar to instagram and I was wondering hoe instagram is able to upload such high quality images and videos. I tried uploading a 1920x1080 res video in my ios app, to Amazon s3 but the video was a few MB so it took a significant amount of time to ipload and retrieve. How can I cut down that time in objective c? How does instagram do it?

Comment: Doing it in a background thread would be a good place to start

Comment: yeah, i already am. I am doing retrieval and upload in a background low priority thread, but since the videos are a few MB they take time to load and it screws up the UI cuz of how long it takes to load and update the main queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image that you are uploading in the cache the same as if you had downloaded it. No need to download it if you already have it. You can display the image at the same time you start uploading it.

You can run Charles Proxy to see what is happening, there is a method to proxy your iPhone through your Mac. See [Using Charles from an IPhone](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/).

Comment: But what I want to do is, upload the image to the server so others can use it see as well. If I upload it to just the phone's cache, others won't be able to see it

Comment: What makes you think that Instagram has no lag? Uploading speed can not be any faster than the network connection to the iPhone and throughput can be further degraded by other users. Note that LTE upload speeds can be several ties faster than WiFi due to upload speeds being slower for most wire-based connections.

Comment: So ywhat you are suggesting is putting the video/image in the device's cache, and then upload it from the cache to the server?

Comment: Yes. No need to download or wait for the image to upload.

Comment: AHHH i gotcha! So instead of waiting for the image to upload directly, just put it in the device's cache and upload it from there. Genius!

Comment: Oh and what about retrieving videos? Some videos that are about 1MB take a tad bit longer to retrieve, is there any way I can make that faster?

Comment: If you have a reason to believe that a video will be requested you can download before the user requests it. Check to see if the user is on cell or WiFi because Cell will probably cost the user. Another way that is nice is when the user requests a video, first download a fast image of the first frame to display, they the user gets quick feedback and something to look at instead of a blank screen.